# How to show notification when app is closed?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to show notification when a value of a child in firebase is changed. I have used below code and it's working when app is in foreground or background and also working in android 7[not tested below 7] even if app is closed. But in android 9 and 10 code is not showing notification when I closes app by swiping from background. Sometimes In android 9 it shows notification for some time after closing and removing app from background. How can I show notification no matter app is running or not?

```
public class ServiceManager extends Service {


public ServiceManager() {}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    showNotificationChanges();
    // Code to execute when the service is first created
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    System.out.println("called");
    showNotificationChanges();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void stopService() {
}
public void getLastModifiedTime(final HomePage.MyCallback myCallback){
    System.out.println("modified time called");
    SharedPreferences spCD = getSharedPreferences("spCD",MODE_PRIVATE);
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(Objects.requireNonNull(spCD.getString("ccm", "Not found"))).child("cd").child("test").child("test1").child("test2");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                String data = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                myCallback.onCallback(data);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
public void showNotificationChanges() {
    getLastModifiedTime(new HomePage.MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(String roll) {
            SharedPreferences spExtra = getSharedPreferences("spExtra",MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(!spExtra.getString("1","No changes").equals(roll)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spExtra.edit();
                editor.putString("1",roll);
                editor.apply();
                showNotification(getApplicationContext());
                //
            }
            int time;
            if(isConnected()){
                time = 10000;
            }
            else{
                time = 120000;
            }
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showNotificationChanges();
                }
            },time);
        }
    });
}
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Network nw = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        if (nw == null) return false;
        NetworkCapabilities actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw);
        return actNw != null &&
                (actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) ||
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH));
    }
    else {
        try {
            NetworkInfo nwInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return nwInfo != null && nwInfo.isConnected();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
void showNotification(Context context) {
    String CHANNEL_ID = "channel";// The id of the channel.
    CharSequence name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowRoutine.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.routine_icon)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 300, 300)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Schedule modified");
    } else {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.routine_icon)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle("Schedule modified");
    }
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setContentText("CR just modified something in routine");
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: In android 9 they have put limitations on `Service` and in android 10 they have put strict limitations on background services. Look for [Work Manger API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)

Comment: @rahat workManager isn't working when app is killed in android 9. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: *in android 10[not 9]

Comment: Can you tell why need to show the notification even if the app is killed or in the background?

Comment: @rahat I am making a app that works with firebase database and I want to notify user if there is any change[in a child].

Answer (score 0):

Your service is killed while the app is in background.

You need to call `startForeground` on your `startCommand` method.

[This is an example to see](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Comment: I have used `START_STICKY`. Shouldn't it be recreated when enough memory is available?

Comment: Won't Foreground services show status bar notification all the time? There are many apps like WhatsApp, messenger lite that shows notification about messages.